# How to invert mount of SDCard

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, stock-android, insufficient-memory

I've Android 4.3 Build JLS356C rooted. It's a wiko WAX. I've three partition in my storage view: the Internal Storage 2Go, Phone Storage 500Mo and my SDCard 32Go. I use SD2link for passing the space and of the applications to my SDcard. I don't know why but my phone storage is full and my android tells me I don't have sufficient space disk. 
Here my df command:

```
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                   440.3M    48.0K   440.3M   4096
/mnt/secure            440.3M     0.0K   440.3M   4096
/mnt/asec              440.3M     0.0K   440.3M   4096
/mnt/obb               440.3M     0.0K   440.3M   4096
/system                755.9M   424.5M   331.4M   4096
/cache                 263.8M     4.4M   259.4M   4096
/data                    2.0G     1.1G   887.4M   4096
/mnt/modem              15.7M     4.2M    11.5M   4096
/mnt/log                78.7M     4.0M    74.7M   4096
/storage/sdcard1        29.0G     6.1G    22.9G   16384
/mnt/secure/asec: Permission denied
/storage/sdcard0       499.0M     1.6M   497.5M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.google.android.ears-1     4.0M     2.2M     1.8M   4096
..../....
```

I modified the fstab.ceres on the root partition but that haven't any effect.

How to tell the Android for put all data on the SDCARD.

Answer (score 0):

Data is stored on the `/data` partition, while "phone storage", `/storage/sdcard0`, is user available memory where you put images, music etc.
If you want to have more space for apps, you need to increase the `/data` partition. If you want to put the data on the external SD card, you'll have to further modify your system.

Comment: I found SD2link tutorial  I created a ext2 partition now I can some obb link on my sdcard